# Get age of cache entry in Ehcache 3.x

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, ehcache-3

I'm using Ehcache 3.8.0 with my Spring 5.x application for caching long running data aggregation. The aggregated data is displayed in a web frontend.

I'm now looking for a way to get the age of an cached element to display it alongside with the data.

Ehcache 2.x stored cache entries as `Element` ([see javadoc](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html)) which had the public method [getLatestOfCreationAndUpdateTime()](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html#getLatestOfCreationAndUpdateTime()) to retrieve the timestamp, at which the cache entry was created or last updated (= the age/freshness of the cached data).

But in Ehcache 3.x cache entries are stored as `Cache.Entry<V,K>` ([see javadoc](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/3.8.0/org/ehcache/Cache.Entry.html)) which is nothing more than a key/value tuple which doesn't provide something like the `getLatestOfCreationAndUpdateTime()` method.

I know that I could use something like cache eventlisteners to store the timestamp seperatly whenever a cache entry is created or updated, but I like to know if there's a more direct way to get the timestamp formerly provided with `getLatestOfCreationAndUpdateTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following manages to capture the internal epoch timestamp of creation of the Ehcache cache entry:

```java
var method = Ehcache.class.getDeclaredMethod("doGet", Object.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
var valueHolder = (Store.ValueHolder<?>) method.invoke(ehcache, key);
return valueHolder.creationTime();
```

The use of reflection is unfortunate but this was sufficient for my debugging purposes.

The `org.ehcache.core.Ehcache` instance in my specific scenario was retrieved inside a custom `org.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener`:

```java
@Override
public void onEvent(CacheEvent<? extends String, ? extends Object> cacheEvent) {
    var ehcache = (Ehcache<?, ?>) cacheEvent.getSource();
    ...
}
```